# Excel COUNTIF Not Working

Tags: excel, function, countif

I have two columns that are adjacent to each other and I need to count the rows in those columns that are less than a value when divided. The function

`=COUNTIF(BG172:BG41552/BH172:BH41552,"<=.1")`

does not work and gives errors.

**EDIT: Per my comment below, a more clarified question: 
I mean to take each individual cell in column BG and divide it by each adjacent cell in BH so BG172/BH172 and if that answer is <= .10 I want to count it and have that done for the whole range of both columns.**

Comment: Can you just do a helper column next to BH and just run the countif on that?

Comment: Interesting... I can try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but see if this is what you are looking for:

=IF(BG172/BH172<=0.1, COUNT(BG172:BG41552) + COUNT(BH172:BH41552), "NOT <= 0.1")

This divides the two adjacent cells, checks to see if that is <= 0.1, if it is the output is the count of rows in the two adjacent columns, added together; if it isn't the output prints "NOT <= 0.1".

Alternatively, if you want to sum the two adjacent columns then divide to see if the value is <= 0.1, this is how you would do that:

=IF(sum(BG172:BG41552)/sum(BH172:BH41552)<=0.1, COUNT(BG172:BG41552) + COUNT(BH172:BH41552), "NOT <= 0.1")

Comment: Sorry if my question is a little vague, I mean to take each individual cell in column BG and divide it by each adjacent cell in BH so BG172/BH172 and if that answer is <= .10 I want to count it and have that done for the whole range of both columns.

Comment: Depending on which column you want to count, this equation is the one you want:

=IF(BG172/BH172<=0.1, COUNT(BG172:BG41552), "NOT <= 0.1") - This counts the rows in the BG column.

=IF(BG172/BH172<=0.1, COUNT(BH172:BH41552), "NOT <= 0.1") - This counts the rows in the BH column.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform any calculation in the range argument within the countif function.

You may try something like this... (Untested)

This is an **Array Formula** which will require a special key stroke **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(((BG172:BG41552)/(BH172:BH41552))<0.1),0))
```

Confirm with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**